Nest js, TypeOrm Connection close issue
I'm using NestJs, and Typeorm (MySQL driver). From time to time I get the 'Connection lost: The server closed the connection.' error.
The server that I'm using closes the connection after 10-15 seconds of inactivity. The main problem is that any request might return 500 error, because the server closed the connection.
I tried different pool configurations but that didn't help.
Here is my TypeOrm config:
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: async () => {
    return {
      type: 'mysql',
      charset: 'utf8mb4',
      extra: {
        pool: {
          createTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          destroyTimeoutMillis: 5000,
          reapIntervalMillis: 1000,
          createRetryIntervalMillis: 200,
          acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000,
          idleTimeoutMillis: 10000,
        },
      },
      logging: ['error', 'warn'],
    };
  },
}),

One of the possible solution is using 'test-on-borrow'. The idea is to validate the request before sending it. But unfortunate typeOrm doesn't have 'test-on-borrow'.
I also tried using a factory. The idea was the same to validate the connection before a query. But it also didn't help
factory: {
  validate: async (connection) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection
        .raw('SELECT 1 + 1 AS health_check')
        .then(() => {
          // Connection is healthy, resolve the promise
          resolve(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Connection is invalid, reject the promise
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  },
},


@Alex, My question is how can I fix this problem? Because of that, I'm facing a situation where any request of my application at any time might return a 500 error because a connection was closed by the server.

Could be a problem related to your server / database config or setup. I suggest checking your database's deployed environment. Try running a standalone backend server (using express or whatever) and see if the issue replicates itself.
